# MERN app on Heroku shows the home page correct, but routes are blank

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

Application link: https://hidden-anchorage-08527.herokuapp.com/

The application has a form on the home page that can be accessed with a button near the footer. Upon submitting the form, a new developer is added to the list with the specified details. These operations, i.e. submitting and retrieving data from the mongoDB database (using the Atlas service) work perfectly.

When the user clicks on a developer, he is redirected to `/dev/:id` to check out further details. This works fine in localhost, but on Heroku, the user is redirected to an empty/blank page. Here is the code:

server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

App.js (from client directory)

```
import React from 'react';
import Landing from './components/Landing';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/devPage/Header';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
          <Route exact path='/dev/:id' element={<Header />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is my directory structure:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: you are having a syntax error in your manifest.json

Comment: how do i fix that? IIRC manifest.json is generated automatically while building right?